# Delaying parameter values/inflow and outflowing rates in deSolve

Tags: r, differential-equations

I am using the `R` package `deSolve` to solve systems of ordinary differential equations. In the 'systems dynamics' literature, delays of the inflowing and outflowing rates can be modelled using average delay times. For instance, the rate of a change of a stock Y at time t could be:

```
dy(t)/dt = inflow(t) - ( outflow(t) / D )
```

where the delay time `D` is, e.g. 4 time steps. The delay is assumed to be an average delay time.

However, another way of modelling delays would be to assume a more discrete event case, where the outflow is equal to the amount inflowing to the stock `D` time units previously, thus:

```
dy(t)/dt = inflow(t) - inflow(t - D)
```

In `deSolve`, we can use the `lagvalue` and `lagderiv` functions with the `dede` solver function to specify delay differential equations which utilise lagged values of the *state variables*, but I cannot seem to find a way of asking `deSolve` to use lagged values of the inflow/outflow rates.

For example, take the simple model:

```
m<- function(t,y,p){
    with(as.list(c(y,p)),{
        inflow <- 100
        outflow <- y*.5
        dy <- inflow - outflow
        return(list(c(dy), inflow=inflow, outflow=outflow))
    })}

fit <- ode(func=m, y=c(100),t=seq(0,10,1),p=c(), method="euler") 

   time        1 inflow  outflow
1     0 100.0000    100 50.00000
2     1 150.0000    100 75.00000
3     2 175.0000    100 87.50000
4     3 187.5000    100 93.75000
5     4 193.7500    100 96.87500
6     5 196.8750    100 98.43750
7     6 198.4375    100 99.21875
8     7 199.2188    100 99.60938
9     8 199.6094    100 99.80469
10    9 199.8047    100 99.90234
11   10 199.9023    100 99.95117
```

Using `dede`, I can make the outflow a lagged value of the state variable at `D = 2` time steps previous:

```
m2<- function(t,y,p){
    with(as.list(c(y,p)),{
        inflow <- 100
        if(t < D) outflow <- y*.5
        if(t >= D) outflow <- lagvalue(t-D,1)*.5
        dy <- inflow - outflow
        return(list(c(dy), inflow=inflow, outflow=outflow))
    })}

fit2 <- dede(func=m, y=c(100),t=seq(0,10,1),p=c(D=2))

   time        1 inflow  outflow
1     0 100.0000    100 50.00000
2     1 139.3469    100 69.67344
3     2 163.2120    100 81.60602
4     3 177.6870    100 88.84349
5     4 186.4665    100 93.23323
6     5 191.7915    100 95.89575
7     6 195.0213    100 97.51064
8     7 196.9803    100 98.49013
9     8 198.1684    100 99.08422
10    9 198.8891    100 99.44456
11   10 199.3262    100 99.66312
```

But now imagine I want the outflow to actually be the inflow `D=2` time steps previous. I want something like:

```
**** Code will not run ****
m3<- function(t,y,p){
    with(as.list(c(y,p)),{
        inflow <- 100
        if(t < D) outflow <- 0
        if(t >= D) outflow <- lagvalue(t-D,inflow)
        dy <- inflow - outflow
        return(list(c(dy), inflow=inflow, outflow=outflow))
    })}
...
```

As far as I can see, `deSolve` does not allow this. Is there an easy way to allow it?

The reason I am interested in mixing a continuous and discrete event type model is in modelling supply chains, where the average time delay may not be accurate for certain products.

Comment: I can think of two scenarios. 1) Inflow is independent of `y`, but is a function of time. In this case, inflow can be defined as a function outside of your ode. If outflow is a function of inflow, then you simply look up inflow with the appropriate lag and calculate outflow using this value. 2) Inflow is a function of `y`. In this case, to calculate outflow you must look up `y` with the appropriate lag, *calculate* inflow based on this value, and then calculate outflow from this inflow. Or have I missed the point?

Comment: Could you provide an example relevant to my code? How would I 'simply look up inflow with the appropriate lag' using the deSolve package?

Comment: Define a function for inflow, say, `calc_inflow <- function(t)10 + 0.1 * t`, then call it from your model `inflow <- calc_inflow(t)`. If outflow is inflow two units of time earlier, then `outflow <- calc_inflow(t-2)`.

Comment: Thanks! This works for the most part.